# Setting a method without jQuery

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I'm using mediaelements.js, and I need to add the `mediaelementplayer()` method to the videos on the page.

I can only seem to get it to work with jQuery though, not with Vanilla JS and since the rest of the site is Vanilla, it seems a waste to include jQuery just for this.

This works:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    defaultVideoWidth: 480,
    defaultVideoHeight: 270,
    features: ['playpause','progress'],
});
```

This doesn't:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

    videos[i].mediaelementplayer({
        defaultVideoWidth: 480,
        defaultVideoHeight: 270,
        features: ['playpause','progress'],
    });

}
```

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLVideoElement> has no method 'mediaelementplayer'`

I've no idea, only thing I can think of is jQuery is returning something different than `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: "Vanilla JS" is a misnomer. You mean "using only the DOM" or "not using any other library." (Using jQuery is also using vanilla/plain/pure/raw JavaScript. Unless you're using it with CoffeeScript, TypeScript, Dart, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mediaelements.js documentation](http://mediaelementjs.com/#howitworks) tells you how you can do this without jQuery:

```
<script>
    // JavaScript object for later use
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player',/* Options */);
    // ... more code ...
    player.pause();
    player.setSrc('mynewfile.mp4');
    player.play();
</script>
```

In your case, you'd do something like this:

```
<script>
    // JavaScript object for later use
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video', {
                     defaultVideoWidth: 480,
                     defaultVideoHeight: 270,
                     features: ['playpause','progress'],
                 });
</script>
```

Comment: what I haven't seen in the documentation is that there is a hard dependency on jquery, zepto, or ender.